# Changing language in tika

Tags: python, nlp, apache-tika, tamil

Is it possible to change the langauge (default detection) for tika?

I am trying to use a pdf file in tamil. (language code 'ta'). But tika is detecting it as 'th' (thai).
Though most characters are recognized well, it not defecting few chars.

see example below, where some 'o' is appearing in between text.

> ஓவச - அக்    ைரும்பாகலைளில் ைருப்பஞ்ொறு பாய்வதால் எழுகின்ற ஓகெயும்;
> வவவலச் சங்கின் வாய்ப்  கபாங்கும் ஓவச - நீர்க் ைகரைளில் உள்ள ெங்குைளிடமிருந்து

```
from tika import language
print(language.from_file(u'pdf/KambaRamayanam1.pdf' ))
```

result is 'th'.
expected is 'ta'

Comment: Take a look at
https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/main/tika-core/src/main/resources/org/apache/tika/language/tika.language.properties and 
https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/main/tika-core/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/language/LanguageIdentifier.java. Tika apparently supports 28 languages, Thai (th) being one of them. Tamil is not supported. Anyway, Tika apparently uses n-gram analysis for language detection. It's a statistical method and will never be very exact. I just tried two PDFs in German and it detected the language as "en" and "th"...

Comment: thanks @RobertPetermeier. I too thought so. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Look here: https://medium.com/@masreis/text-extraction-and-ocr-with-apache-tika-302464895e5f at the "Identify language" section. Tika endpoint language/stream is used to recognize the language. It works fine for the native pdfs, but for the scanned pdf the returned value is 'th'. The root cause is: the OCR is not used for language detection (only the simple text extraction) so when the ocr is required (scanned pdfs or jpgs) than the detected value is th

Answer (score 1):

1. in the TesseractOCRConfig class, there is a method setLanguage
2. When You use tika server You can set the language header: X-Tika-OCRLanguage
   the list of tesseract languages is here: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata

Comment: thanks for your response @marek.kapowicki. I am able to get this done through tesseract seperately (for which i first convert pdf to jpg).  But with Tika I directly give the PDF. I am not sure how to integrate Tesserect languabe options in Tika. From your response I understand that there is a  possibility. Would you mind directing me to any write up on the same?

Comment: The tika can be used to extract the text from pdf in few ways: https://tika.apache.org/1.24/api/org/apache/tika/parser/pdf/PDFParserConfig.OCR_STRATEGY.html
1. no_ocr -> works fine with native pdfs. Tika extract text from pdf without using tesseract
2. ocr_only -> tika uses the tesseract under the hood to ocr the given pdf (than u can use the tesseract parameters. https://tika.apache.org/1.24/api/org/apache/tika/parser/ocr/TesseractOCRConfig.html
look here: https://github.com/marekkapowicki/nlp

Answer (score 0):

Tika can handle the pdf in either ocr mode (works fine with scanned pdf) or the no_ocr mode - than tika sends the request to tesseract

1. be sure that your tika is using the ocr either in code

   PDFParserConfig::setExtractInlineImages(true) //is important
   PDFParserConfig::setOcrStrategy(PDFParserConfig.OCR_STRATEGY.OCR_ONLY)

or using headers in tika server:

```
X-Tika-PDFextractInlineImages: true, X-Tika-PDFocrStrategy: OCR_ONLY
```

2. than your tika is using the tesseract and you can change the tesseract configuration: https://tika.apache.org/1.24/api/org/apache/tika/parser/ocr/TesseractOCRConfig.html

To get the big picture I m strongly recommended to look at my java project https://github.com/marekkapowicki/nlp and the blog post: https://medium.com/@masreis/text-extraction-and-ocr-with-apache-tika-302464895e5f

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be two parts to this question, if I understand correctly; the OCR and the Language Detection. They are interlinked from what I understand from the comments to the other questions and answers.

### OCR for Indian Languages

In terms of OCR, by default, Apache Tika uses the *eng* Tesseract model only unless you tell it to use others. You can do this by setting them in the TesseractOCRConfig, either through:

1. Creating your own TesseractOCRConfig.properties file and placing it on the classpath in the appropriate package
2. Sending an appropriate header on the request to Tika Server in the REST call.

(Option 2 can also be used to override defaults you've set in one)

This allows you to give a list of one or more Tesseract models to load for use during the OCR.

You can use some of the ones provided by Tesseract, or customs ones such as Tesseract Models for Indian languages [here](https://indic-ocr.github.io/tessdata/) that you install or build.

Once installed you just need to use the relevant model name in the language list in the *TesseractOCRConfig*

Both are explained in more details on the Wiki:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/TikaOCR

### Language Detection

Because you are using the tika-python model, which in turn uses Tika Server, you are not calling the language detector from tika-core referenced in the other answer. You are actually using the *OptimaizeLangDetector* and it's default models, with profiles supported for the languages shown [here](https://github.com/optimaize/language-detector).

There is no Parsing going on in the */language* endpoints you are using, and thus no OCR, with it merely using the raw String or what it reads within the InputStream sent.

To maximise the chance of a good result, you'll want to use:

```
from tika import parser, language
content = parser.from_file("sample.pdf") 
print(language.from_buffer(content))
```

Together with *TesseractOCRConfig* setup to use the appropriate models that match the scripts you are sending in, you should get a reasonable result.

```
from tika import parser, language
headers = { "X-Tika-OCRLanguage": "eng+tam" }
content = parser.from_file("sample.pdf", xmlContent=False, requestOptions={'headers': headers})
print(language.from_buffer(content))
```